# I'm trying to make an appointment system, but the data won't show up to my Jtable

Tags: java, user-interface, debugging, jtable, encapsulation

I'm using Java and Windows Builder in Eclipse to create the GUI, while also implementing encapsulation to store the information. There are two sides in my appointment system, User and Registar. The user will type in their information at the text field, and then press the button for request. When we switch to the registar's panel where the table is, there isn't anything displayed in it.

Here are my codes.

```
import queuemanagement.QueueManagementSystem.AppointmentRequestPanel;

public class AppointmentRequest {
    
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private String middleName;
    private String email;
    private String documentType;
    private String proofOfPayment;
    private String purposeOfAppointment;
    private String trackingCode;
    private AppointmentRequestPanel appointmentReq; 
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDocumentType() {
        return documentType;
    }

    public void setDocumentType(String documentType) {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }

    public String getProofOfPayment() {
        return proofOfPayment;
    }

    public void setProofOfPayment(String proofOfPayment) {
        this.proofOfPayment = proofOfPayment;
    }

    public String getPurposeOfAppointment() {
        return purposeOfAppointment;
    }
    
    public void RequestAppointmentPanel(AppointmentRequestPanel appointmentReq) {
        this.appointmentReq = appointmentReq;
    }

    public void setPurposeOfAppointment(String purposeOfAppointment) {
        this.purposeOfAppointment = purposeOfAppointment;
    }

    
    // Constructor
    public AppointmentRequest(String firstName, String surname, String middleName, String email, String      documentType,
            String proofOfPayment, String purposeOfAppointment) {
        
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.email = email;
        this.documentType = documentType;
        this.proofOfPayment = proofOfPayment;
        this.purposeOfAppointment = purposeOfAppointment;

    }
 }
```

Here's the code for the panel that has the text fields, I also shortened this code because of how long it is with the other labels that aren't needed for this problem.

```
public class RequestAppointmentPanel extends JPanel {
    public RequestAppointmentPanel(DefaultTableModel tableModel) {
        
        this.tableModel = tableModel;
        appointmentRequestPanel = new AppointmentRequestPanel();

    private AppointmentRequest retrieveAppointmentRequest() {
        // Get the values entered by the user
        String firstName = textField_firstName.getText();
        String surname = textField_surname.getText();
        String middleName = textField_middleName.getText();
        String email = textField_email.getText();
        String purpose = textArea_purposeOfAppointment.getText();
        String proofOfPayment = textField_proofOfPayment.getText();
        String documentType = comboBox_documentType.getSelectedItem().toString();

        // Create and return an instance of AppointmentRequest
        return new AppointmentRequest(firstName, surname, middleName, email, documentType, proofOfPayment, purpose);
    }
        
    private void addFileRequestButton(JPanel panel) {
                
        btnFileRequest = new RoundedButton("File a Request");
        
        btnFileRequest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  // Check if required fields are filled
                
                if (isFieldsFilled()) {                
                    
                    // Retrieve the appointment request information
                    AppointmentRequest appointmentRequest = retrieveAppointmentRequest();

                    // Pass the appointment request data to the AppointmentRequestPanel
                    appointmentRequestPanel.addAppointmentRequest(appointmentRequest);
                    
                    // Display success message and clear the entered information
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File request submitted!", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    clearFields();
                                                        
                } else {
                    
                    // Display an error message or prompt the user to fill in the required fields
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all required fields.",                 "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    
                }        
                
            }
        });
        
        btnFileRequest.setText("File a request");
    }
}
```

Lastly, the class that has the table.

```
public class AppointmentRequestPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTable appointmentTable;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    
    
    public AppointmentRequestPanel() {
        
        setSize(1016, 637);
        setBackground(new Color(249, 249, 249));
                
       appointmentTable = new JTable();
       //create the table model with appropriate column names
       tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
       tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Last Name", "First Name", "Middle Name", "Email", "Document Type", "Proof of Payment", "Purpose"});
       setLayout(null);
      
       appointmentTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
       appointmentTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
       appointmentTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
       appointmentTable.setModel(tableModel);
       
       //create and configure the table to display the appointment requests
       JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(appointmentTable);
       scrollPane.setBounds(42, 90, 931, 509);
       scrollPane.setViewportView(appointmentTable);
    
       add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       
       JLabel lblAppointmentRequest = new JLabel("Appointment Request");
       lblAppointmentRequest.setForeground(new Color(49, 62, 138));
       lblAppointmentRequest.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 40));
       lblAppointmentRequest.setBounds(42, 0, 406, 91);
       add(lblAppointmentRequest);
       
    }
    
    public void displayAppointmentRequest(AppointmentRequest appointmentRequest) {
        // add the appointment request data to the table model
        Object[] rowData = {
            appointmentRequest.getSurname(),
            appointmentRequest.getFirstName(),
            appointmentRequest.getMiddleName(),
            appointmentRequest.getEmail(),
            appointmentRequest.getDocumentType(),
            appointmentRequest.getProofOfPayment(),
            appointmentRequest.getPurposeOfAppointment()
        };
        tableModel.addRow(rowData);
    }
    
    public void displayRow(Object[] row) {
        tableModel.addRow(row);
    }
        
    public DefaultTableModel getTableModel() {
        return tableModel;
    }

}\`\`\`
```

I also can't use database for this. Please tell me if my format for asking a question is wrong, I'm still new to this site. And if my code is messy, sorry about that.